# gdi+ generic error when drawing image on Graphics object

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi+

Consider the following code running in a windows service.

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(printImage);

for (int rows = 1; rows <= thumbRows; rows++) {
    for (int cols = 1; cols <= thumbColumns; cols++) {
      using (Image thumbImage = new Bitmap(resourceQueue.Peek()))
      {  
          g.DrawImage(thumbImage, targetRect, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

          resourceQueue.Dequeue();
          if (resourceQueue.Count == 0) break;
      }
    }
}
```

The code draws a list of images after making them smaller onto another image.
It works fine most of the time but sometimes an exception is thrown in the middle of the loop on the Image thumbImage = new Bitmap. The exception is "A generic error occurred in GDI+". It always happens after the 13th image is created no matter what images are used.

After googling it seems that this a common problem when saving files but the difference here is that no file is saved. An image is drawn on a Graphics object.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: We can't see the code with the bug, it is located in the code that created the bitmap before it got pushed into the queue.  With good odds that, since you are careful about using *using*, probably does something like disposing a memory stream.  It bombs when the image memory manager needs to dip into the native pixel data to render the image.

Comment: resourceQueue is a queue of strings holding the paths to the images it doesnt hold images. thumbImage can be safely disposed after drawing on the Graphics object right?

Comment: I did not guess at this queue containing strings.  No idea why 13 is an unlucky number.  It's Friday.

Comment: Are the images above being used anywhere else in the code (e.g. in another thread)?

Comment: Nope they arent used at that moment only for making them smaller and print them on the new image.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the stream used to create the Bitmap (if that is what it is) is closed. They have to stay open for the life of the Bitmap. You can copy the stream into a new MemoryStream, then close the original.